# Find a file in React

Tags: reactjs

How to search a specific named file in a folder using React ?

My file name is like below

```
var filename =  window.location.hostname ;
```

Now I would like to search the file like below

```
if(require('../public/service/filename.json')) {

//do something
}
else {
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following way:

```
const checkFileExist = (path) => {
  try {
   return require(`${path}`);
  } catch (err) {
   return null;
  }
};
```

and use it on your component

```
 if(checkFileExist('../public/service/filename.json') === null) {
   // something
 } else {
   // something
 }
```